# AngularJS 1.3 to 1.5 transformRequest broke, solution for my specific situation?

Tags: angularjs

Long story short. I am really not an AngularJS guru. Our site upgraded from 1.3 to 1.5. This one thing is breaking.

We used to inject an HTTP header via transformRequest in a factory named 'api':

```
.factory('api', function($resource) {
    function add_auth_header(data, headersGetter) {
        var headers = headersGetter();
        headers['Authorization'] = ('Basic ' + btoa(data.username +
                ':' + data.password));
    }
    // defining the endpoints.
    return {
        auth: $resource('/api/v1/auth/', {}, {
            login: {method: 'POST', transformRequest: add_auth_header},
            logout: {method: 'DELETE'},
        }),
```

Later on in the same file, this is called like so:

```
.service('auth', function($cookies, $rootScope, api) {
    this.user = null;
    this.login = function(credentials) {
        var log = api.auth.login(credentials);
        log.$promise.then(function(data){
            // on good username and password
            this.user = data;
        });
```

As you can see, it calls api.auth.login with the credentials. I have verified that the transform request is being called, the headers are being fetched properly by headersGetter(), and that hanging the headers[] object no longer changes it like it used to in 1.3. Fiddler verifies that the request no longer has an Authorization header in it like it did in 1.3, and the Django server that gets the request also agrees.

I've read in a few places that the transformRequest functionality 'broke' in 1.4, but those posts have always been in the context of making an $http request, not providing an api service through a factory, and haven't made much sense to an AngularJS newb like me. I have no idea where I would start changing how Authorization is injected.

Can anyone point me the right way?

Comment: Seriously, no comment on why the downvote? This is an entirely legit question.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is still facing this, the change was under breaking changes in the changelog for 1.4.

I feel the fix speaks for itself. Note that the function add_auth_header is not invoked but rather is passed.

```
.factory('api', function($resource) {
    function add_auth_header(data) {
        // as per HTTP authentication spec [1], credentials must be
        // encoded in base64. Lets use window.btoa [2]
        return 'Basic ' + btoa(data.data.username + ':' + data.data.password);
    }
    // defining the endpoints.
    return {
        auth: $resource('/api/v1/auth/', {}, {
            login: {method: 'POST', headers: { 'Authorization': add_auth_header     }},
            logout: {method: 'DELETE'},
        }),
```